# Unable to store data to database in android

Tags: android, database

```
public int insertContacts(String n, String p) 
{ 
  String query = "select * from contacts where number='" + p +"'"; 
  cursor = db1.rawQuery(query, null); 
  if (cursor == null) { 
     count++; 
     String sql = "insert into contacts(name, number) values('" + n +"','" + p + "')";
     db1.execSQL(sql);
  } 
  return count; 
}
```

This code was supposed to save 'name' and 'number' to 'contacts' table if the number is not found from this query-

```
String query = "select * from contacts where number='" + p +"'";
```

But no data is saved to the table even if it is empty. Why ?

Comment: 1) don't run this code again or check if contact is already in database 2) you can use something that is not "boring to you"

Comment: @Selvin I need to check whether new contacts are added in phone. So I only need to store the newly added contacts when the code is run again. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` won't ever return a `null` for a `Cursor` so your conditional if block is never executed.

Instead of

```
if (cursor == null)
```

use

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
```

to test whether the cursor is empty.